# Authenticating to Oracle REST data services as admin

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle12c

i'm working on an android app connected to a database, the database has more data than any tablet can  handle, so after some research i found many solutions, most of them consisted of implementing a webservice between the app and the database itself, i found this and this, i just installed the latest version of ords, had a couple issues to get the web interface to work but now that it's working, i cannot login, i did find a couple solutions but none of them seems to work , any ideas ? what are the default identifiers supposed to be ? i'm lost here with like 50 tabs

thank you

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/867x679q90/571/22qo.png

https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/753x796q90/855/u9b3.png

ps : i checked the apex_public_user and the apex_040200 users and they were 'expired' is that normal ?

if you need any more information please let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, so i found a solution, seing how apparently my default admin password got messed up

i ran a ' find /oracle/ -iname 'apxchpwd.sql' Search command

once i got the location of the file, i logged in sqlplus as sysdba, then ran @[complete_apxchpwd.sql_path] got prompted for the new password, typed it in, and voila